# How to display the pop up correctly on mouse over using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see here in my sample that my pop up is showing at the edge. How can I check the edge thus displaying the pop up on the right side.

[image: The popup displays at the end of the screen]

Another example is this. This one shows the pop up at the bottom. I want it to display wherein the full pop up will show.

[image]

You can view the actual demo here www.mydubaitrip.com/restaurants.aspx

My code is this

```
$(".thumbsUpNav").live("mouseenter", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).children("span").attr("id");
    var pURL = $('#txtTopLevelNode').val() + 'WhyBookList.aspx?id=';
    pID = "#whyBookReviewRating" + id;
    $(".whyBookReviewRating").css({"display":"none"});
    //$(this).children('.arrow_pop_up').css({top: $(this).offset().top + "px"});

    if (id != "") {
        $(pID).empty();
        if (($(pID).length == 0) || ($(pID).length == 1)) {

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',     
                type: 'GET',
                url : pURL + id.substring(1, 6) + '&type=' + id.substring(0,1),
                success : function (data) {
                    $(pID).append(data);
                }
            });
        }  
        pos = $(this).offset();    
        var width = $(this).children("span").width();     

        $(pID).css({   
            left: (width) + 'px'
        });
        $(pID).stop().css({"display":"block"});  
    }
    else if (id == "") {
        $(".whyBookReviewRating").css({"display":"none"}); 
    }
});

$(".thumbsUpNav").live("mouseleave", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("rel");
    pID = "#whyBookReviewRating" + id;
    $(".whyBookReviewRating").css({"display":"none"});  
});
```

Comment: Ive added a codepen that may help you. It's for displaying tooltips and takes into account the position of the element on the screen, and how much the page has scrolled etc... It may be of use to you and should be pretty easy to tweak for your needs - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/Dewdo

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough space in the right side in the page at www.mydubaitrip.com/restaurants.aspx

the hand Icon is in the most right end of the page, if you add anything there the horizontal scroll will appear! why do you want the box to be appeared in the right side of that hand Icon while there is no enough space for it?